# Nesting tables - legit?

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-table, semantic-markup

I am creating a restaurant menu, and I'm not sure if I should use tables or not, and especially if I should use nested tables at all. Is this valid? I'm thinking a restaurant menu could be considered tabular data.

Creating the structure with nested tables is incredibly convenient and stable across any browsers, but I don't know if this would be the proper way to do it. Here is what it looks like:

http://jsbin.com/ejoqad/1/edit

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>PIZZA</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>onions,cheese</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>3.5 $</td>

    </tr>
  </table>
```

Also, will this structre be likely to cause me troubles down the road when i try to make the design optimised for different devices?

Comment: You should not be using HTML tables for layout, it would be better to use lists instead (e.g. `ul`)

Comment: well thats not exactly layout though

Comment: If you're not using a table for layout, then it doesn't matter how the table responds to various devices. It should still be a table.

Comment: There's nothing inherently invalid about tables or nested tables (if you think about it, why would the spec include something that was invalid by its own definition?). If it's tabular data, then that's exactly what tables were designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly valid, but you should probably just use `<br />` instead of a whole table just to break a line.

Comment: hm thats a good point. the second table could be left out i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6.1), the same effect can be achieved with less markup, using the `rowspan` attribute.

The basic idea is that `<td>` elements can span multiple rows or columns (using `rowspan` for rows and `colspan` for columns) by setting the attribute to an integer value. Accordingly, `<td rowspan="2">` is a cell spanning two rows of the table.

These attributes were present in HTML 3.2, so compatibility is very good (I tested back to IE8 with no issue).

Here's the updated jsbin for reference: http://jsbin.com/ejoqad/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your menu is a table of data so using an HTML table is semantically correct, irrespective of layout. Good work. However I don't know why you need to use two nested tables.

Answer (score 0):

HTML tables are meant for storing tabular data, like in a matrix.

Could possibly your menu be a list? It could use uls then. Which are more flexible to style a layout than a table.

If your intention is purely present tabular data and it has no means in layout, do it and try to layout it later :p

If you have any intention of using it as layout container, then you're thinking wrong. Any situation I consider using table for layout is when it's troublesome to do with CSS, like columns with different heighs, or when I want without JS to have some areas with static widght/height and something in middle with flexible.